# Django RQ handles long serializer job

Tags: python, django

I have validator in the model. It does validation and then validated data will be saved to database.

**Problem:**
Validation and commit to database takes very long time. 
Therefore I decided to use `Django-rq` to handle the time consuming task

`views.py`

```
def save_serializer(serializer, request):
    serializer.save()
    if bool(serializer.errors):
        # If it has no errors it will be empty dictionary and bool({}) is False
        msg = serializer.errors
    else:
        msg = serializer.data

    email = EmailMessage(
        'Message From jobs.siamsbrand.com',
        msg,
        settings.C0D1UM_SENDER,
        [request.user.email]
    )
    email.send()


class PriceListExcelFileList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    permission_classes = (DRYPermissions,)
    queryset = PriceListExcelFile.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PriceListExcelFileSerializer

    def perform_create(self, serializer, request):
        """
        :param serializer: 
        :return: 
        """
        django_rq.enqueue(save_serializer, serializer, request)

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        """
        I need to override the default behaviour because I am going to use rq and let it be an email notification
        :param request: 
        :param args: 
        :param kwargs: 
        :return: 
        """
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        self.perform_create(serializer, request)
        headers = self.get_success_headers(serializer.data)
        data = {
            "id": "Processing",
            "file": "The response will be email to " + str(request.user.email) + " shortly",
            "permission": "-"
        }
        return Response(data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED, headers=headers)
```

**Error Messages:**

```
File "/Users/el/Code/siam-sbrand/portal/apps/price_list_excel_files/views.py", line 52, in create
    self.perform_create(serializer, request)
  File "/Users/el/Code/siam-sbrand/portal/apps/price_list_excel_files/views.py", line 40, in perform_create
    django_rq.enqueue(save_serializer, serializer, request)
  File "/Users/el/.pyenv/versions/siam-sbrand/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django_rq/queues.py", line 208, in enqueue
    return get_queue().enqueue(func, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/el/.pyenv/versions/siam-sbrand/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rq/queue.py", line 274, in enqueue
    job_id=job_id, at_front=at_front, meta=meta)
  File "/Users/el/.pyenv/versions/siam-sbrand/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django_rq/queues.py", line 60, in enqueue_call
    return self.original_enqueue_call(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/el/.pyenv/versions/siam-sbrand/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django_rq/queues.py", line 56, in original_enqueue_call
    return super(DjangoRQ, self).enqueue_call(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/el/.pyenv/versions/siam-sbrand/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rq/queue.py", line 227, in enqueue_call
    job = self.enqueue_job(job, at_front=at_front)
  File "/Users/el/.pyenv/versions/siam-sbrand/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rq/queue.py", line 292, in enqueue_job
    job.save(pipeline=pipe)
  File "/Users/el/.pyenv/versions/siam-sbrand/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rq/job.py", line 465, in save
    connection.hmset(key, self.to_dict())
  File "/Users/el/.pyenv/versions/siam-sbrand/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rq/job.py", line 429, in to_dict
    obj['data'] = self.data
  File "/Users/el/.pyenv/versions/siam-sbrand/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rq/job.py", line 227, in data
    self._data = dumps(job_tuple)
TypeError: cannot serialize '_io.BufferedReader' object
"POST /api/price-list-excel-files/ HTTP/1.1" 500 20430
```

Comment: Meanwhile waiting response. I am figuring out the `TypeError` on this

Comment: Seems like I have to attack this problem with `fork` or `thread`. Hope I am going to the right direction

Comment: Thread is the answer to my case

Comment: Can you share your project's django and celery lib version? This might help to investigate in detail.

Comment: @SohamNavadiya. Thank you for your response. I don't use `celery`. Why I use rq. Because I got order to follow

Answer (score 0):

It can handle plain function not an instance. Then I have to use `thread` to do long time consuming task